# A (counter)-example in probability theory.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Let $\mathcal{D}$ the set of dyadic intervals (open on the right and closed on the left) in $[0,1)$ (i.e. $I\in\mathcal{D}$ if and only if $\exists n\in\mathbb{N_0}, \exists k\in\{1,...,2^n\}, I=[\frac{k-1}{2^n},\frac{k}{2^n})$). I'm wondering if there exists a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset[0,1)$ such that $$\forall I\in\mathcal{D},\exists \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N\chi_I(a_n)=:\mathbb{P}(I)\in[0,1],$$
but such that there exists a sequence of mutually disjoint dyadic intervals $(I_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathcal{D}$ whose union is a dyadic interval $I\in\mathcal{D}$ and $$\mathbb{P}(I)\neq\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mathbb{P}(I_k).$$
Notice that if the disjoint sequence is replaced by an arbitrary finite disjoint family $I_1,...,I_n$, the fact that equality holds in the previous formula is immediate from the definition of $\mathbb{P}$, but, for the denumerable case, a switch of limits problem pops up, so I suspect that such a "pathological" example could exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(a_n)$ be any sequence in $[0,1)$ converging to $1$.  Then $\mathbb{P}(I)$ is defined for any dyadic interval $I$, and is $1$ if $\sup I=1$ and is $0$ otherwise.  This fails to be countably additive, since it vanishes on each of $[0,1/2),[1/2,3/4),[3/4,7/8),\dots$ but is $1$ on their union.

Comment: I see that it is not so pathological after all... Can I ask if you know any (hopefully, necessary and sufficient) "intuitive" condition on the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in order to obtain that equality necessarily holds? My problem is that imposing the switch of limits condition is not so sensible from an experimental physicist point of view who records $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ as the results of a sequence of measurement

Comment: A necessary condition is that there is no subsequence of $(a_n)$ of positive density which converges to a dyadic rational from below (since if there were, you could make a similar counterexample to mine).  I believe that is also sufficient but have not checked all the details.

Comment: Probably I'm going to commit the whole day in trying to prove o disprove such a result, so I've the following question: when you say that you believe that it is also sufficient but you have not checked all the details, what strategy do you have in mind in order to prove the result? Thanks in advance

Comment: Here's the idea.  Formally adjoin a right endpoint to every dyadic interval.  This turns $[0,1)$ into a Cantor set, and the dyadic intervals into the "intervals" of the Cantor set formed by its gaps.  The function $\mathbb{P}$ then extends to a Borel measure on the Cantor set by the Caratheodory extension theorem (the key point being that there are no ways to write one of our intervals in the Cantor set as a disjoint union of infinitely many others, by compactness, so $\mathbb{P}$ is vacuously countably additive on them).

Comment: Now, if the measure of each of our new right endpoints is $0$ under the extension of $\mathbb{P}$, we can just remove them from all our intervals to conclude that $\mathbb{P}$ is actually countably additive on our original half-open intervals.  The condition that each right endpoint has measure $0$ should correspond to there being no subsequence of $(a_n)$ of positive density that converges to a dyadic rational from below.